# How can I check if the created_in column is none or not inside triggers?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

**The column and trigger structure inside the users' table**

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `created_in` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

| Trigger | Event | Table | Statement | Timing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | insert | users | IF NEW.created_in = "" THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE "45000"; END IF | before |

I'm trying to cancel the insert if the created_in column was none but does not work.

How can I check if the created_in column is none or not?

> Version of MySQL is 5.7

Comment: Do you really need a trigger? I'd consider a basic check constraint here.

Comment: Please add result of show create table users and show create trigger yourtriggername

Comment: @jarlh check the update

Comment: @P.Salmon Check now.

Comment: Table validation occurs before the trigger is executed so trigger cannot do what you want.

Comment: @P.Salmon The condition is working already when I check if the user name is none or not, But it does not want to work with datetime type. I'm just checking if datetime that I insert is none or not

Comment: The trigger condition won't check the value for NULL.

Comment: There is no name in your table definition. It would help if you published your trigger code and the insert code which proves your assertion meanwhile  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a788b9a9d88bcb859e1a14783b78186e

Comment: Trigger not needed. Simply enable strict SQL mode, and the attempt to insert incorrect date value will fail.

Comment: @P.Salmon The users table has more than 14 columns but I show the column related to the question only. The trigger body is inside the statement column above. I tried to execute show create trigger trigger_name. But It is showing the table like above without the command

Comment: @Akina Could you explain more please, Currently, I check if the column is none or not, Using PHP but I want to do it in MySQL without PHP code if that is possible

Comment: [Server SQL Modes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger not needed, sesstion strict mode is enough:

> ```
> set session sql_mode = '';
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `users` (
>  `created_in` date NOT NULL
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
> insert into users values ('');
> select * from users;
> ```
>
> ```
> | created_in |
> | :--------- |
> | 0000-00-00 |
> ```

> ```
> set session sql_mode = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES';
> ```

> ```
> insert into users values ('');
> ```
>
> ```
> Incorrect date value: '' for column 'created_in' at row 1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a169162099cf10e385c9d8d931b4dbd2)*

Comment: Can I apply strict mode on a specific column without applying it on all tables?

Comment: @T38416 You cannot. But you can set needed mode immediately before your INSERT and restore it immediately after, so it will effect one query only. Session mode changes does not influence on another sessions. Moreover, needed SQL mode setting for a session is good practice, if not then changes in global SQL mode may break your application easily. In common all needed values are set in additional commands property of the connection object.

Comment: Check the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klnGq.png), I applied this command `set session sql_mode = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES';` but still I can insert empty values on names and dates etc...

Comment: @T38416 It seems that your MySQL is 5.7. If so then adjust the mode to be set and add needed values into. `set session sql_mode = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO';`

Comment: Same, The values in the column look like 0000-00-00, Maybe STRICT_ALL_TABLES does not work in 5.7?

Comment: @T38416 There is a link to the fiddle in the answer. Please open it and check the MySQL version used... It is possible that this is your client/framework/library issue which sets the SQL mode before each query or uses separate (or random from the pool) connection for each query.

Comment: Note: I inserting the date from phpMyAdmin from insert tab. Maybe because of that does not prevent the insert?

Comment: @T38416 I don't know. You may investigate - for example, enable General log temporarily and look what queries (including hiddenly added ones) are sent to the server in practice.

Comment: If I executed `set session sql_mode = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES';` and `insert into users values ('');` together, It prevent the inserting. But if I executed `insert into users values ('');` alone still insert the data to table

Comment: @T38416 I have predicted the source of this above.

Comment: I'll search for the problem and tell you what happens with me, I'll mark the answer as correct after finding the solution. Thank you.

Comment: @T38416 It seems that you need in something similar to ```$db = new PDO('mysql:host=myhost;dbname=mydb', 'login', 'password', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET SESSION sql_mode=\'STRICT_ALL_TABLES\''));``` on PHP level. Read the manual about this.